# Update the UI based on backend data and re render and view programmatically set data on React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to update the CheckboxInput value based on the value I receive via the backend API calls data. As per the below code value.locked (boolean) to set in the UI and dispatch its respective dispatcher. Everything work well but setting the checkbox to check does not work. Basically, the UI does not update. Reducer state updates.

If anyone can share a working sample is much appreciated

```
import { useReducer, useRef } from "react";

export const StatusViewFilters = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const tagsList = useSelector(selectStartpointsStatusTagsList);
  const usersList = useSelector(selectStartpointsStatusUsersList);
  const filter = useSelector(selectStartpointStatusFilter);
  const savedFilters = useSelector(selectStartpointsStatusFilters);
  const pagedMetadata = useSelector(selectStartpointStatusPagedMetadata);
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState();
  const refContainer = useRef(null);
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getTagsList());
    dispatch(getAllUsers());
    dispatch(getAllFilters());
  }, []);

  const search = (el) => {
    dispatch(getStartPointSagaStatusList({ ...filter, ...pagedMetadata }));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    search();
  }, [filter]);

  const { t } = useTranslation();

  // To Do set and update react UI and state accordingly
  const setStatusAccordingToSavedFilter = (value) => {
    console.log(value);
    if (value.locked) {
      // wants to set the value of the checkbox to check

      // This doesn't work ChceckboxInput does not change the check box to check state based on the value.locked?

      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.inputRef));
      this.inputRef.CheckboxInput.checked = true;
      document.getElementById("123").checked = true;
      dispatch(setStartPointSagaStatusLockedSearchFilter(value.locked));
    }
    if (value.searchByFreshness) {
      dispatch(setStartPointSagaStatusFreshnessFilter(value.searchByFreshness));
    }
  };
  
    <div>
      <CreatableSelect
        Id="123"
        placeholder={t("Saved filters drop down")}
        onChange={(el) => {
          const filters = el.data[0];
          setStatusAccordingToSavedFilter(filters);
        }}
        options={savedFilters}
      />
    </div>

    <div className="border rounded flex">
      <CheckboxInput
        ref={inputRef}
        change={(checked) => {
          dispatch(setStartPointSagaStatusLockedSearchFilter(checked));
        }}
        label={t("locked")}
      />
    </div>

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be modifying the DOM directly in a React app. Use a selector to get the current locked state and set `checked` directly on the checkbox when your component renders.

```
const isLocked = useSelector(...)

<CheckboxInput
  checked={isLocked}
  change={(checked) => {                          
    dispatch(setStartPointSagaStatusLockedSearchFilter(checked))
  }}
  label={t('locked')}
/>
```

Comment: When trying the above approach im getting React Hook "useSelector" is called in function error.

Comment: It’s pseudo code. You’d need to fill in your selector function in your component.

Answer (score 1):

the best approach is to bind the `checked` property of `CheckboxInput` to a state:

```js
const initialValue = useSelector(...)
const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(initialValue);
//...
<CheckboxInput
  checked={isChecked}
  onChange={(checked) => {
    setIsChecked(checked);
   //... additional work
  }}
/>;
```

Comment: Tried this as well couldnt find any luck

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: setIsChecked already defined Can you provide working code sample which i can refer into

Comment: you juste have to use another name for the setter function it seems that you have already a function with this name so change is to this `const [isValChecked, setIsValChecked] = useState(initialValue);` then inside `onChange`: `setIsValChecked(checked);`